# How do I fetch all messages in a channel?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord, discord.js

I'm trying to fetch all the messages in a channel, but the error I get is `cannot send an empty message.`

```
var str = bot.channels.cache.get('729038947380101170').messages.fetch({ limit: 10 });
message.channel.send(str);
```

The channel has messages for sure. What is wrong with the `fetch()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with `fetch()` it just returns a promise so you need to `await` that promise

```js
const channel = bot.channels.cache.get('729038947380101170')
const messages = await channel.messages.fetch({ limit: 10 });
messages.forEach(msg => message.channel.send(msg.content));
```

Comment: It still gives the same message of "cannot send an empty message". @Syntle